# Cannot resolve import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient; on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-api, documentation

[image]

I am trying to import the Android.gms library but it says no documentation found. How can I fix it?

Comment: I tried but those solutions didn't solve it

Comment: Can you show your **build.gradle** how you import the library?